# is it atomic for writing a struct to same global memory location in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, atomic

for example:

```
struct Point
{
    int x,
    int y;
};
```

If all threads write their own `Point` into the same location in global memory in the same time, is it possible that the final result `Point` in that location has `x` value of thread A and `y` value of thread B?

This question is closely related to [Concurrent writes in the same global memory location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953955/concurrent-writes-in-the-same-global-memory-location) and [Is global memory write considered atomic in CUDA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714860/is-global-memory-write-considered-atomic-in-cuda)

Comment: @RobertCrovella: There you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*[This answer was copied from a comment that should have been an answer.]*</sup>

> Is it possible that the final result Point in that location has x value of thread A and y value of thread B?

Yes. To avoid such a scenario you need to write a `Point` as a single atomic value (ie, reinterpret a `Point` as a `double` or `int64` and use an atomic set).